JSON deserialization not working in Jetpack Compose
To decode (deserialize) JSON data in Jetpack Compose seems quite simple, however I've encountered a problem that I can't solve. I'm using the latest version of Android Studio and I'm not sure whether the .decodeFromString() function works in AS or I should use IntelliJ IDEA for this? Here's my code:
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
}


import kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@ExperimentalSerializationApi
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            JSONsibleTheme {
                DecodedText()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Serializable
data class User(val id: Int, val name: String)

@ExperimentalSerializationApi
@Composable
fun DecodedText() {
    val jsonString = """
    {
        "id": 722549,
        "name": "John Smith"
    }
    """
    val deserialized = Json.decodeFromString<User>(string = jsonString)
    Text(
        text = "${deserialized.name}, ${deserialized.id}"
    )
}

I can't run this code either on a simulator or a real device because the @Serializable annotation doesn't apply (it's underlined in yellow). The Warning says:
// kotlinx.serialization compiler plugin is not 
// applied to the module, so this annotation would 
// not be processed. Make sure that you've setup 
// your buildscript correctly and re-import project.


You also need to apply the plugin to your root build.gradle.kts file
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "$kotlinVersion" apply false
}

and your app build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}


Did you add to the project level plugins block too? Please check the updated answer.

Also, please make sure the plugin version matches your kotlin version.

Please check in the logcat whats wrong. Its probably a runtime error and not a compilation error.

In your json string it should be "id" and not "user_id". They keys have to match the data class.

Sure. Best of luck!

I would like to complement @AtickFaisal answer (anyway thank you, Atick, for pointing the right direction), because with all these settings specified (including compose compiler plugin), my Jetpack Compose app runs without errors and successfully decodes JSON data.
Project build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "2.0.20" apply false
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.kotlin.serialization)
    }
}

Module build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
    // other implementations
}

libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.5.2"
kotlin = "2.0.20"

[libraries]
kotlin-serialization = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization", version.ref = "kotlinSerialization" }
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "kotlinxSerializationJson" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }

Here is a screenshot.
